# Non Editable Edit Field highlight issue

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-editfield

I have a non editable edit field in my screen. In order to differentiate between editable and non editable field i have set the background of the non-editable field to light gray as in the code below:

```
  Border nonEditableBorder=BorderFactory.createRoundedBorder(new XYEdges(5, 5, 5, 5),Color.LIGHTGRAY,Border.STYLE_FILLED|Border.STYLE_TRANSPARENT);
  EditField textField=new EditField(EditField.NO_NEWLINE|EditField.FOCUSABLE|DrawStyle.RIGHT);
  textField.setBorder(nonEditableBorder);
```

Now on the non-editable field when i scroll the trackball to the right or left the text gets highlighted in white as shown in the image below:
[image]

I do not want the text to get highlighted. Can someone please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In addition to setting the border i also set the background to the same color as the border and that solved my problem.

Comment: add your comment as an answer, and then mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting the border i also set the background to the same color as the border and that solved my problem.